# The operation of Whitney sum induces a natural abelian group structure on the set of stable isomorphism classes of bundles

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-construction

Suppose $ξ$ and $η$ are two vector bundles over $X$. We say $ξ$ and $η$ are stably isomorphic if $ξ\oplus ε^{j}$ $\cong η\oplus ε^{k}$  for some
j, k. Let $KX$ denote the set of stable isomorphism classes of bundles over $X$.
[$X$ denotes either a manifold or a finite-dimensional simplicial or $CW$ complex; $ε^{i}$
denotes the trivial k-plane bundle.]

My question is how to prove "the operation of whitney sum induces a natural abelian group structure on $KX$ ". I couldn't prove this.

We have this theorem:
Let $ξ$ be a $C^{r}$ k-plane over an n-manifold $M$, $0 ≤ r ≤ ∞$.Then there is a $C^{r}$ n-plane bundle $η$ over $M$
such that $ξ\oplus η\cong_{r} M×R^{s}$.

This is a problem in the " differential topology of Morris W.Hirsch " (chapter4.classification).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you need help showing that for all $\xi$ there exists an $\eta$ such that $\xi \bigoplus \eta$ is a trivial bundle?

Comment: Without knowing any particular algebraic topology, I'm deeply skeptical of your suggestion to use some classification. How could such an approach possibly be natural?

Comment: I'm not sure that I have to use the classification to prove

Comment: If your space $X$ is compact you can find a proof in [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf), proposition 2.1.